# Str formatting in Python3.9

Tags: python, string, formatting

I am using Python 3.9 and trying to write the function

```
def greet(request, name):
    return HttpResponse(f'Hello, {name.capitalize}!')
```

Using `f` to format the string but it is not working. Any ideas on why?

Comment: It would be helpful to expand on "not working", but presumably because you didn't *call* the method.

Comment: Just an FYI, there are people out there who insist on creating first names with interesting capitalisation strategies, such as BriAnna or AeraBella. I'm not a big fan of those sorts of bone-headed decisions (the kid's going to spend a substantial proportion of their life explaining to people how to "spell" their name) but you may want to take it into account.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Error messages, unexpected behaviours and outcomes, _expected_ behaviours and outcomes, etc. are all important. Please include them whenever asking a question here or elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

`capitalize` is a method of the `str` object.
Therefore you need to add parenthesis for it to be called:

```
def greet(request, name):
    return HttpResponse(f'Hello, {name.capitalize()}!')
```

Furthermore, `name.capitalize` is really just the reference to the function.
Try running the following inside a python interpreter:

```
print(str.capitalize)
```

You could even return this function:

```
def cap_str(string):
    return string.capitalize

s = "programming in python"
capitalize_s = cap_str(s)
s_cap = capitalize_s()
print(s_cap)
```

I don't know how this would be particularly useful, but returning a function in general is pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

Can you print the error message? I suspect your error is that you want `name.capitalize()` rather than `name.capitalize`

Ah - this has already been added!

Comment: FYI there will not be an error, the string will simply be formatted with `<function .....>`